# Bootstrap 3 Modal won't pop up when triggering from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Looking at some video tutorials I follow what has been done but don't seem to get to modal of the register link to trigger.

Here is the link I want to trigger:

```
<li><a href="#register-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register-modal">Register</a></li>
```

Here is the modal that should be triggering

```
<!-- Register Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="#register-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>Register</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I assume that there should be jQuery to be implemented after looking at other answers but i do not see how come if the jQuery comes from the bootstrap. The Bootstrap 3 documentation seems to do the same as I did http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` attribute shouldn't have a hashtag.

Change

```
<div class="modal fade" id="#register-modal" role="dialog"></div>
```

to:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="register-modal" role="dialog"></div>
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/crudkr19/)

Comment: Thanks that did it. So the modal div should not have the hashtag but  the anchor tag should ref?

Comment: @Beast_Code Correct. The anchor element's `data-target` attribute is essentially a selector. For example, it could be changed to `data-target=".modal"` in order to select all element with the `.modal` class. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/fjx6fynv/)... it could also be changed to `data-target=".modal#register-modal"` in order to select an element with class `.modal` and an `id` of `#register-modal` - [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/5w5t013q/)... as you can see, you can basically specify any selector for the `data-target` attribute's value.

Comment: That's interesting. The tutorial I followed had that #.

Comment: @Beast_Code Which tutorial?